# Code to click a link and show it in a table on the same page

Tags: html

I have created a table with four links, what I want is to make the pages I linked show inside the table each time I click on the link.  I want the content of each page show in this table.  Thanks awaiting your help.

This is the HTML code for the table:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
     <td bgcolor="#0000FF"><div align="left"><a href="../../pageone.html">Data Model</a><a href="page1.html"></a></div></td>
     <td bgcolor="#0000FF"><div align="left"><a href="../../pagetwo.html">Skill Acquisition</a></div></td>
     <td bgcolor="#0000FF"><div align="left"><a href="../../pagethree.html">Business Dev.</a></div></td>
     <td bgcolor="#0000FF"><div align="left"><a href="../../pagefour.html">E-book Sales</a></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="4"><div align="left">
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         </div></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an iframe in ur website, 
Put the table in a separate html file, and load this file into the iframe. That way the new website would be opened in thr place where the table is (in the iframe)